# Liquibase is not taking the configurations from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql

I have a spring boot application. And I have configured liquibase to create tables. I have few issues though. The tables are not getting created inside the schema and in the location provided in application.yml. Also, if i change the username from default sa to "root", the spring boot liquibase scripts fail with the error "wrong username or password".

Here is my application.yml file:

```
    debug: false
    server:
      port: 9110
      servlet:
        context-path: '/v1/ss-db-service'
      tomcat:
        remoteip:
          protocol-header: x-forwarded-proto

    spring:
      jpa:
        properties:
          hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: none
        show-sql: true

      h2:
        console:
          enabled: true
          path: /h2-console
          settings:
            web-allow-others: true

      liquibase:
        enabled: true
        contexts: dev
        user: sa
        password:
        database-change-log-table: 'db_changeset_log'
        database-change-log-lock-table: 'db_changeset_lock'
        change-log: classpath:liquibase/changesets/MASTER_changeset.xml
    #    default-schema: AGENCY_SS_REQUEST

    datasource:
      agency-ss-request:
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:AGENCY_SS_REQUEST;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema.sql';
        username: sa
        password:

    logging:
      level:
        'org.hibernate.SQL': INFO
        'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql': INFO
        'liquibase.statement': WARN
        'liquibase.resource': WARN
```

I tried setting the scehma with `default-schema`. But spring boot application fails to start with "Schema not found error".

This is my schema.sql file:

```
   CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS AGENCY_SS_REQUEST;
   SET SCHEMA AGENCY_SS_REQUEST;
```

Here is liquibase configuration files:

Here is my liquibase.properties file: (Though, changing anything in this file does not seem to take effect:

```
    ### Maven Liqubase Config File
    url=jdbc:h2:mem:AGENCY_SS_REQUEST;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 
    'classpath:schema.sql';
    username=sa
    password=
    driver=org.h2.Driver
```

Master_changeset.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.0.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>
    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle, mssql, mariadb"/>
    <property name="clobType" value="clob" dbms="h2"/>
    <property name="clobType" value="clob" dbms="mysql, oracle, mssql, mariadb, postgresql"/>
    <property name="uuidType" value="varchar(36)" dbms="h2, mysql, mariadb"/>

    <!--  Initial USER_PRODCER_INFO Schema  -->
    <include file="./REQUEST_TABLE_20230116_changeset.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

REQUEST_INFO_20210203_01.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
                   xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.0.xsd">

     <changeSet id="REQUEST_INFO_20210203_01" author="snagesh">
         <createTable tableName="ss_request">
              <column name="ss_request_id" type="VARCHAR(36)">
                 <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
              </column>
       --- there are more fields
        </createTable>
       </changeSet>

    </databaseChangeLog>
```

with the above configuration, if i run the application, i see in the spring boot console that liquibase has created tables in a random memory location. if i open that in h2 console i see the below things:

[image]
Here, tables are created outside the schema. also in some random memory location.

If I access the h2 console i have configured in application.yml, just the h2 tables are there. none of my tables are created in the location.

[image]

This is my entity file:

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "ss_request", schema = "AGENCY_SS_PORTAL")
    public class SSRequest {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name = "ss_request_id", nullable = false)
      private Integer ssRequestId;
    --- more fields
```

My questions are:

- why can't i see my tables in jdbc:h2:mem:AGENCY-SS-PORTAL this location, but in a random location(I get this random location from spring boot application logs)?
- Why are not my tables getting created inside the schema. and why does the application fail to start if i enforce the schema creation with default-schema: AGENCY_SS_REQUEST
- why does the application fail with username/password error, if i change the password from sa to root. is liquibase looking at any other configuration?

Note: I am doing this project on intelliJ. so if any extra configuration is needed, let me know

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of issue then I came to know that only superusers can able to create the private schema in Postgres

Option: 1

By default public schema will be available so if there is no requirement of private schema, then you can create directly tables which will be part of default public schema

Option: 2

Create private schema using superuser and then create tables inside that private schema